# Call function on element (that does not have unique id) on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

When hovering over generic elements of the same type, I want to execute a function on this elements that will perform an animation. However as these elements do not have unique ids I'm not sure how to uniquely identify them in JavaScript. Is there a way to use the this key word for this? I do not want to give them all unique ids because a huge amount of the same element and it seems redundant. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Heres some code I was playing with to try and get this to work. Preferably the simpler the code or using basic javascript better.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").hover(function(){
    this.color = red;
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen on hover? Maybe this can be done with CSS only.

Comment: I dont think so, I want the elements to perform an animation, but I want the animation to continue even if the person stops hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`red` is not a variable, it is a string. So that you have to use `'red'`:

To set the color using JavaScript you have to use `style` property :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").hover(function(){
    this.style.color = 'red';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Frist</span> <br>
<span>Second</span>
```

**OR:** Using jQuery use `.css()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({color: 'red'});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Frist</span> <br>
<span>Second</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can user class as a selector**

give the same class to all `<span>` element

Try Following

```js
    $('.hoverTest').hover(function(){
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        }, function(){
        $(this).css("color", "");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='hoverTest'>Your Span Element</span><br/>
<span class='hoverTest'>Span 1</span><br/>
<span class='hoverTest'>Span 2</span><br/>
<span class='hoverTest'>Span 3</span><br/>
<span class='hoverTest'>Span 3</span><br/>
<span class='hoverTest'>Span n</span>
```

Refer [Jquery Hover()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover) for more details